# how to access samba on a guest Linux behind the VirtualBox NAT?

Tags: windows, linux, networking, virtualbox, nat

On my laptop, I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 under WinXP using VirtualBox 3.1.2. 
I want a setup where:

1. The guest can freely access the internet.
2. The host can access the guest files via Samba.
3. The setup must work whether or not my ethernet/wifi ports are connected.

Is it possible?

#1 works with NAT and bridged networking.

#2 works with bridged and host-only networking.

Bridge-based setup doesn't work if relevant physical port is not connected. At the office, the laptop is connected to wifi or ethernet. At home, wifi only.

Is there a workaround? Am I missing anything?
I hope I'm making my question clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would try setting up two separate network adapters.

- Adapter #1 would be your current #1 setup: NAT to allow access to the internet available.
- Adapter #2 would be a [host-only](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#network_hostonly) setup to provide the connection between the host and the guest for the Samba shares.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I have no idea why I missed it when playing with the different setups...

Comment: and @noamtm, I'm trying to make this solution work with no luck. 

My smb.conf is:
`[global]
interfaces = eth1
security = user
[testsh]
   path = /home/my_user_name
   guest ok = yes
   browseable = yes
   read only = no`

And my interfaces are:
`eth0: inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
eth1 :192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I configured `eth1` as host-only, and `eth0` as NAT. I tried accessing and mounting `\\10.0.2.15\testh` and `\\192.168.56.101\testh` from the host OS (Windows), but I receive no response.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to create two bridged virtual NICs, one to the physical wireless interface and one to the physical wired interface. As long as one (or both) of the physical interfaces is connected you should have access. I generally try to avoid NATing as much as possible, since it tends to create a lot of headaches in the long run (as you have seen with file sharing).

Comment: Does bridged mode work with wireless devices? I remember there's some trouble with it because Wireless devices ignore packets that aren't intended for it (something like that).