# Virtualbox Ubuntu 11.10 Server Guest + Windows 7 Host: Access Guest Files from Host

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, samba

I have a Ubuntu 11.10 Server Guest machine on Virtualbox and a Windows 7 Host.

I can use SSH to connect and use VIM to edit development files, but ideally, I would like to use a Windows text editor like Sublime Text 2 to edit the files on the Guest machine.

I am using Virtual 4.1.10 currently.
Any suggestions?

Comment: [how to access samba on a guest Linux behind the VirtualBox NAT?](http://superuser.com/q/104717)

Comment: You can also store all those files on a VirtualBox shared folder, accessible as a normal host folder and under /mount in the guest system. This may be more reliable, with how finicky Windows' network sharing can be at times.

Comment: I just changed the network adapter from NAT to Bridged Network and now I am able to connect. Is this the preferred way to go for development servers? I can connect to the web server by just typing in the IP address of eth0 from ifconfig into the browser